# Get list of users under a user using Azure graph API

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-ad-graph-api

I am looking to implement a method something like below:

If I pass a manager Id to my method, then it needs to give me the list of users whoever report to that manager.

I could find reference where, if I provide a user Id, it gives me the manager to whom the user reports.

GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/john@contoso.onmicrosoft.com/$links/manager?api-version=1.6

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations

But I need vice-versa. Something like, I provide the manager Id and I need the list of users under that manager.

Comment: What do you mean `under that user` exactly? It's not a term I'm familiar with when discussing active directory. Can you relate it to a specific feature and give the technical name please

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say member. Need to fetch the direct members under the passed parameter user_id

Comment: users don't have members. Do you mean you want to get all users who are members of a _group_?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Ok thanks. That's a lot clearer now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-directreports?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http looks like it might be what you need

Comment: Yes. But I am having problem in implementing it. For GraphServiceClient, do I need to add any reference from Nuget? Because I couldn't find any. Also, it is showing example with 'me'. I think I have to replace it with the userId that I will be passing into my method right?

Comment: Yes you would replace it with the ID. You can find examples on other websites including this one. I think the nuget package is simply called Microsoft.graph

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Install the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-net-sdk).

Use [Client credentials provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#ClientCredentialsProvider) to generate the authProvider.

Code sample:

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantID)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var directReports = await graphClient.Users["{upn or user_object_id}"].DirectReports
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```